# IPython cell magics?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My IPython Notebook (IPython 3.1.0, Python3.4, windows7) shows all the magics I would expect when I do `%lsmagic`, however when I try to run the `%%python2` magic, I get an error: `Couldn't find program: 'python2'`, do I have to set an environment variable for the cell magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have Python 2 installed on your machine. When you type:

```
python2
```

on the command line Python 2 has to a start.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked, still I don't find it the most elegant solution since I had to add the python2 directory to the environment path and change the name of the python exe file (it was originally simply python.exe). Maybe there is a way to configure ipython so to point the cell magic call to the executable directory?

Comment: On Windows you can set an alias: http://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line